# Why is a new instance of HttpClient not loading the updated version of a website?

Tags: vb.net, http, uwp

I am trying to download data at a certain intervall from a website which is constantly updated, for e. g., a [weather station](http://weather.namsearch.com/).

I am working on a UWP-App in VB.Net.
To do this, i am calling a sub every 60 seconds with the help of a dispatchertimer.
The function creates new instances of a Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient and a Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage which then use the fixed URI to download the website.
The content of the HttpResponseMessage is then converted to string and the data is extracted and processed.

```
Async Sub GetDataTest()

        Dim result as String
        Dim myUri As Uri = New Uri("http://weather.namsearch.com/")
        Dim myClient As Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient = New Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient
        Dim myResponse As Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage = New Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage
        myResponse = Await myClient.GetAsync(myUri)

        result = myResponse.Content.ToString
End Sub
```

Everytime the Sub is called, the content of the responsemessage is the same as in the previous call, although the data in the website (e. g. windspeed) is changing. What is the reason for this and how can I avoid this issue?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need to create a new instance here `Dim myResponse As Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage = New Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage`.  That instance actually gets thrown away on the next line.  That won't fix your main problem though, just a general note.

Comment: You should also try to change your `sub` in to a function that returns a `Task<string>` so that exceptions propagate correctly through async.  It would have the signature `Async Function Task(of String)  GetDataTest()`, and your would `return result` at the end.

Comment: The example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient) gets the content of the response a bit differently to the way you're doing it. I've never used those types so I'm not sure of the right way to go but what happens if you use `Await myResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` in line with that example?

Comment: I would contact them to ask what is the preferred way of getting their data. Especially if you query the page every minutes. Maybe they would like you to use their csv file instead.

Comment: Maybe, The website writes cache in your local data. You could try to disable cache write behavior. `Dim filter As New HttpBaseProtocolFilter()
filter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache
Using client As New HttpClient(filter)
End Using`